# Reading contents of excel file in python webapp2

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2

I have two files namely sample.csv and sample.xlsx, all those files are stored in blobstore.I am able to read the records of csv file(which is in the blobstore) using the following code

```
   blobReader = blobstore.BlobReader(blob_key)
   inputFile = BlobIterator(blobReader)
   if inputFile is None:
      values = None
   else:
      try:
         stringReader = csv.reader(inputFile)
         data = []
         columnHeaders = []
         for rowIndex, row in enumerate(stringReader):
            if(rowIndex == 0):
               columnHeaders = row
            else:
               data.append(row)
         values = {'columnHeaders' : columnHeaders, 'data' : data}
      except:
         values = None

      self.response.write(values)
```

The output of the above code of a sample.csv file is

```
{'columnHeaders': ['First Name', 'Last Name', 'Email', 'Mobile'], 'data': [['fx1', 'lx2', 'flx1x2@xxx.com', 'xxx-xxx-xxxx'], ['fy1', 'ly2', 'fly1y2@yyy.com', 'yyy-yyy-yyyy'], ['fz1', 'lz2', 'flz1z2@zzz.com', 'zzz-zzz-zzzz']]}
```

Using the xlrd package, i am able to read the excel file contents, but in this i have to specify the exact file location

```
   book = xlrd.open_workbook('D:/sample.xlsx') 
   first_sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)
   self.response.write(first_sheet.row_values(0)) 
   cell = first_sheet.cell(0,0) 
   self.response.write(cell.value)
```

Is there any way to read the excel file contents from the blobstore, i have tried it with the following code

```
   blobReader = blobstore.BlobReader(blobKey)
   uploadedFile = BlobIterator(blobReader) 
   book = xlrd.open_workbook(file_contents=uploadedFile)
                    (or)
   book = xlrd.open_workbook(file_contents=blobReader)
```

But it throws some error TypeError: 'BlobReader' object has no attribute '**getitem**'.

Any ideas? Thanks..

Comment: Well, there's http://www.python-excel.org/ , https://github.com/python-excel and http://xlwings.org/ , the first three results under a Google search for "python excel"

Comment: Read the content from blob store and use xlrd.open_workbook(file_contents=content_from_blob_store))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking into the [doc](http://www.lexicon.net/sjmachin/xlrd.html#xlrd.open_workbook-function) for open_workbook in the xlrd package doc, it seems that when you pass "file_contents", it's expecting a string.

Then you need to look into turning a Blob into a String, which can be done with [BlobReader.read()](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/refdocs/google.appengine.ext.blobstore.blobstore#google.appengine.ext.blobstore.blobstore.BlobReader), which gives you a string of the read data.

Comment: @Yuvaraj happy to have helped :). Enjoy the platform!