# openpyxl load_workbook from backend service

Tags: google-app-engine, openpyxl

I have some openpyxl code in my backend service (google app engine) and I'd like to load a file from google cloud store / blobstore, but passing the file stream (via blobstore reader) doesn't appear to be valid for load_workbook. xlrd has an option to pass file contents ([Reading contents of excel file in python webapp2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31380301/reading-contents-of-excel-file-in-python-webapp2)). Is there something similar for openpyxl?

```
blobstore_filename = '/gs{}'.format('/mybucket/mycloudstorefilename.xlsx')
blob_key = blobstore.create_gs_key(blobstore_filename)
blob_reader = blobstore.BlobReader(blob_key)
blob_reader = blobstore.BlobReader(blob_key, buffer_size=1048576)
blob_reader = blobstore.BlobReader(blob_key, position=0)
blob_reader_data = blob_reader.read()
load_workbook(blob_reader_data)
```

The error is:
UnicodeDecodeError
'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 11: ordinal not in range(128)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the missing link:
[Using openpyxl to read file from memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20635778/using-openpyxl-to-read-file-from-memory)

I needed to convert the file stream into bytes.

```
from io import BytesIO
...
wb = load_workbook(BytesIO(blob_reader_data))
```